# Why is my INSERT INTO sql query not working?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I have this line:

```
result = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(:username, :hash)",
                        username=request.form.get("username"), hash=hash)
```

that when executes, fails to insert anything into my database.
I'm honestly so confused as to why this doesn't work, and I even copied over a SQL query from a previous program I made just to make sure. I'm not getting any "error" but on the terminal, the line is yellow instead of green, which it usually is when the query is successful.

[image]

My db looks like this:

[image]

To be specific, my desired result is to insert both the username and hash into my database.

Comment: check https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=92287 if this thread helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my (uninformed) point of view, you're trying to insert a new row with only 2 column values. Yet the other column values cannot be null.

So insert the whole row?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
import pyodbc
user='sa'
password='PSWD'
database='NORTHWND'
port='1433'
TDS_Version='8.0'
server='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
driver='FreeTDS'

   con_string='UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;PORT=%s;TDS=%s;SERVER=%s;driver=%s' % (user,password, database,port,TDS_Version,server,driver)
   cnxn=pyodbc.connect(con_string)
   cursor=cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(name,address) VALUES (?,?)",('thavasi','mumbai'))
   cnxn.commit()
```